# How to use persistence.xml and hibernate.cfg.xml in JUnit tests via eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jpa, junit, jpa-2.0

I have been searching for an answer during quite a long time before coming here and ask this question.
My problem is very simple : I cannot run any JUnit test when using the JPA Entity Manager API. It seems that my test is not reading the `persistence.xml` file.

When I call `new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory()`, it works like a charm but an exception is thrown when calling `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myapp")` is:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for
>   EntityManager named myapp at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
>     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
>     at com.myapp.Test01.setUpBeforeClass(Test01.java:22)

My JavaSE  project has the following structure :

```
myapp
++src/main/java
   ++com.myapp.model
      ++// My entity classes are here
++src/test/java
   ++com.myapp
      ++Test01.java
++src/main/resources
  ++hibernate.cfg.xml
  ++META-INF 
    ++persistence.xml
```

and `persistence.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="myapp" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="hibernate.cfg.xml"></property> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess would be that `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence` is not on your classpath. That's not in the main Hibernate jar, it's in the hibernate-entitymanager or some such jar.

A couple of quick experiments would be to do, in the code immediately before the call to `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory()`:

```
System.out.println(getClass().getResource("META-INF/persistence.xml"));
```

And:

```
System.out.println(Class.forName("org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"));
```

It would also be wise to check that Eclipse is copying your resources; do a Project > Clean and then look in your Eclipse build output directory to see if persistence.xml is where you expect. I have sometimes run into cases where Eclipse doesn't copy resources for some reason or other.

Comment: Thnak you very much. That's the right solution hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.7.Final.jar was missing in the classpath with any complaints about a missing class in the classloading process. FYI, this JAR is located in HIBERNATE_HOME/lib/jpa and Eclipse does not include it by default

Comment: I've gone round this loop enough times that i've actually put together a tiny project with everything needed to use Hibernate via JPA: https://bitbucket.org/twic/jpaquickstart/src . It includes a Gradle build script which pulls in all the dependencies, and also generates persistence.xml and various other boilerplate files.

Answer (score 9):

Put the configuration in `src/test/resources/META-INF`.

Comment: Actually, I had to put mine in `src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`.

Comment: Thanks @acdcjunior, I updated my answer accordingly.