# How to convert a non-gradle JUnit project (that uses Hibernate and EntityManager) to a gradle Junit project and keep it working

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, junit, gradle

I have a JPA/Hibernate project that implements a number of repository interfaces (I use DDD) and I have another project that tests the first one, by using JUnit 4. My IDE is Eclipse Luna. I learned later that I could made a single project with both runtime and testing code, but at this moment, I have them separated in those two projects.

Everything works perfectly so far.

Now, I decided to convert my test project in a **Gradle** project. After converting, I created this `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    baseName = 'dominio.hibernate.tests'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    compile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
    runtime fileTree(dir: '../dominio/build/libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: '../dominio/build/libs', include: '*.jar')
    runtime fileTree(dir: '../dominio.hibernate/build/libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: '../dominio.hibernate/build/libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'postgresql:postgresql:9.0-801.jdbc4'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.6.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:4.1.0.Final'
    compile "javax.enterprise:cdi-api:1.0-SP1" 
    compile "javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5" 
    runtime "org.jboss.weld:weld-core:1.0.1-SP1"
    compile project(':Dominio')
    compile project(':DominioHibernate')
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

The compile works perfectly, but when I run the tests, **iether in Eclipse or by Gradle**, I have the folowing exception

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named unidades
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at     dominio.hibernate.tests.HibernateUnidadeOrganizacionalRepositoryTests.setUp(HibernateUnidadeOrganizacionalRepositoryTests.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ... the rest of the stack
```

I stress that nothing changed in the Java code and it ran perfectly before Gradle came into the scene.

So, it appears that after converting the project to a Gradle one, `persistence.xml` is not being reachable anymore during the JUnit run, and I can't get the `EntityManager` instance I need to perform the tests.

I browsed a large number of posts about problems relating JUnit, resource files and Gradle, but no one of them could give me an idea about how to fix the problem.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the title to make it clear that the problem is specific to Hibernate/EntityManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **Peter Niederwiser** answer and comments, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885295/how-to-use-persistence-xml-and-hibernate-cfg-xml-in-junit-tests-via-eclipse) in StackOverflow and some reading on Gradle documentation about [Java plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) I was able to figure it out what was wrong and fix it. Detais below:

1. Peter suggestions on updating the `resourceDir` for **both main and test** source sets were done (see Peter's answer and his comments)
2. There was a Hibernate package missing for runtime environment; I updated the dependency block to add it:

   dependencies {
       ...
       compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.6.Final'
       runtime 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.6.Final'
       ...
   }

Only this two steps combined fixed my problem. The **META-INF** folder was copied to the right place and the (now present) Hibernate package was there to handle `persistence.xml` in order to create the `EntityManager` instance my testing code needed.

Answer (score 0):

To successfully run tests that make use of Hibernate, Hibernate resources and related code have to placed in the same output directory:

```
sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
```

This is only a problem for tests, as they have the output directories on their class path, rather than the Jar/War. (This avoids the need to build a Jar/War for running tests.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work. I added the line you suggested right after the `dependencies` block. However, I noticed that the folder **META-INF** and the file **persistence.xml** does not exist anywhere under the build folder. As far as I understand, it should be there, right (sorry, I'm a newbie still with a lot to learn)?

Comment: With above line, `persistence.xml` will end up somewhere under `build/classes/main`. If not, there is likely some fundamental problem with your build (scripts). You can try to add `sourceSets.test.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.test.output.classesDir`, but I doubt it will make a difference.